# Locked out for trying to correct a sequence of BEAST tag errors

Tags: discussion, tags, rejected-edits

The `beast` tag was created for a Ruby on Rails software. When the Beast attack occurred the Ruby on Rails tag was used by people that did not see that it existed for the Ruby on Rails software. I have created a [beast-attack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beast-attack) tag in order to correctly tag these posts.

Several of the suggested edits have been rejected. I cannot correct the description of the [beast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beast) tag as I have been locked out of editing. See this [rejected edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16797881). The description was added much later than the tag was created which is how it came to be incorrect.

My reasoning for stating that the [beast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beast) tag was created for Ruby on Rails is a May'09 - Beast Ruby on Rails SO question. It has [beast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beast) tag & all edits from May'09 have [beast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beast) tag. [What is SSL BEAST](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/S/ssl_beast.html) states that it is "Short for Browser Exploit Against SSL/TLS, SSL Beast is an exploit first, revealed in late September 2011". These details mean to me that the use of the [beast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beast) tag for Ruby on Rails happened year(s) before the beast attack and therefore the use of the [beast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beast) tag for the attack was a change in meaning.

[image: May'09 - Beast Ruby on Rails SO question]

Comment: I think it would have been better if you had started with an meta question *before* you went filling the suggested edit queue. Then the wiki would have been in place and you would have had a meta post to direct reviewers to. Now we need to fix this after the fact but that is not really what your asking here. What do you expect as an outcome now, what do you want us to do and can you elaborate on that in your question?

Comment: I find both tag incredibly misguided. Beast is a common word in english, and common too in the programming context. Ruby beast library (?) should have a [ruby-beast] tag. The beast attack tag shouldn't exist. It's not related to programming anymore than other attacks, yet we don't have tags for everyone of them.

Comment: I made a sequence of corrections. I saw an incorrectly tagged post, I made a valid tag it for and did the edit. Some of the corrections were approved. Nothing in that provoked me to ask a question. Then some were rejected. The reasons for the rejects make no since to me. At this point I cannot contribute any more edits. If I am a bad editor and should be locked out then I see no action needed. If not then, how is the lock removed?

Comment: You created a tag that has no usage guidance )because that edit was *also* rejected) and then asked reviewers to approve a bunch of tag only edits where you replace a tag that appeared to be correct (because the description had been changed) with a new, blank tag. From the POV of the reviewers the edit appeared to be wrong.

Comment: "I made a valid tag", no, you didn't. "You should always favor existing tags; only create new tags when **you feel you can make a strong case that your question does cover a new topic** that nobody else has asked about before on this site." I don't see how to correctly implement tsl using openssl is a new topic.

Comment: So, nobody's mentioned that the pictured question is off topic yet?

Answer (score 5):

Neither [the tag history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/41239505/revisions) nor [the tag excerpt history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/41239506/revisions) back your initial belief or premise that this tag was *primarily* meant for Ruby.  I won't deny the odd question here and there, but it seems like that use was usurped and then *codified* by someone adding that tag usage and description for it.

Since it seems like most of the questions in the [beast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beast) tag are meant for the BEAST attack *anyway*, the path of least resistance would be:

- Create a new [ruby-beast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-beast) if it doesn't exist (good luck - it doesn't seem like this project exists anymore...)
- Edit questions which are explicitly about Ruby and the Beast forums and also have been tagged [beast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beast) with [ruby-beast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-beast)
- **Add a descriptive tag wiki** and **tag excerpt** to the [ruby-beast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-beast) tag.

Creating a meta post would've been the better thing to do, as reviewing changes to tags or making tag-only changes can be finicky.

Comment: Maybe the last bullet should happen after the first, assuming that is an ordered list?

Comment: Added the screen shot to the question showing why it sure looks like the Ruby usage was the actual original meaning.

Comment: I did not even go down the path of re-tagging the original questions that were about Ruby as I thought that since they were first I would leave them alone & just clean up the mistakes that were made, presumably because someone added the description to the beast tag describing it as for the attack w/o  knowing that it started being for ruby.

Comment: @C.W.HolemanII:  I maintain that the history for the tag didn't indicate it.  Just because someone's using it for one purpose doesn't mean that it's formally codified.